# Animating the VictoryLine component inside the victory-native library causes a lot of heat in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, charts, real-time, victory-native

I am developing charts with React Native.
What I want is a real-time chart, and I want to draw a line chart with animation whenever data is added.

like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjQd8.gif)

Although it was implemented using victory-native,
If you specify the animate property, it seems that a lot of calculations occur.

iOS is running hot because of this issue (Android also runs a lot of calculations).

If there is a way to optimize animation or a library that can be implemented such as gif, please recommend it.

my code is like this

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, View} from 'react-native';

import {VictoryChart, VictoryLine} from 'victory-native';

const App = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(
      () =>
        setTest(prev => {
          if (prev.length > 90) {
            return [];
          } else {
            return [...prev, {x: prev.length + 1, y: Math.random() * 100}];
          }
        }),
      1000,
    );

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <VictoryChart width={Dimensions.get('screen').width + 100}>
        <VictoryLine
          animate={{onLoad: {duration: 1000}}}
          data={test}
          // labels={(datums) => {console.log(datums.y); return datums.y}} // Many logs are taken.
          interpolation="monotoneX"
          style={{data: {stroke: '#fff', strokeWidth: 1}}}
        />
      </VictoryChart>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Sorry for the lack of English using a translator, and thank you for your reply in advance.

When I removed the animate attribute, the heating problem disappeared.

Also, set the data update cycle to 5 seconds,
If you set the animation duration to 1 second,
It seems that there is a lot of calculation in 1 second, and the calculation is stopped for 4 seconds.